# More than one graphQL API configured. Could not infer which API to call Amplify Flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql, aws-amplify

I have been working on this problem for a few days and have no idea why I keep seeing this error when I attempt to query something using Graph QL API in Flutter. I only have 1 endpoint in my amplifyconfiguration.dart file. I would really appreciate help and please let me know if I need to share on of the files in my project.